BloodHound windows
When I am trying to run bloodhound on windows with command:
curl -L https://ghst.ly/getbhce | docker compose -f - up 

it doesn't generate password so I can't log in. What can I do? Reinstallation of docker didn't help.
Im using this:
https://github.com/SpecterOps/BloodHound
I tried reinstall docker and some command to change password but it didn't help.

"it didnt generate password" - how did you reach this conclusion? Password is usually printed to stdout on the bloodhound container at startup

It supposed to be on the screen in powershell

Well, what do you see on the screen currently? If you're seeing a bunch of access log entries: scroll up


Install Docker Compose and ensure Docker is running.
Run curl -L https://ghst.ly/getbhce | docker compose -f - up
Locate the randomly generated password in the terminal output of Docker Compose
In a browser, navigate to http://localhost:8080/ui/login. Login with a username of admin and the randomly generated password from the logs


It supposed to be in the logs but its not there what can i do men

You see the installation instructions on screen?

I scrool and its not there belive me

Yes, everything is haw IT supposed to be but there's no generated password

So what can i do

I will try to install IT on the virtual machine see if something change :p
